# Compare 2 CSV files based on a column and then merge them

Tags: python, pandas, csv, sorting, merge

I have 2 CSV files and I would like to merge them together.

The second CSV should be integrated into the first, so to speak, so both IP columns should be compared and the ports should then be copied into the first CSV for the correct IP.

I would be very happy if someone could help me :)

I am able to use any Python module

If it's necessary, it would be creating a third file to which everything is exported.

First CSV:

| IP | System | Contact | DNS | Ports |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 192.168.2.1 | Gateway | xns | gati |  |
| 192.168.2.2 | VM1 | etd | vm1etd |  |
| 192.168.2.3 | VM2 | rtf | vm2rtf |  |

As you can see the ports column is still empty because they are saved in the second CSV looking like this:

| IP | Ports |
| --- | --- |
| 192.168.2.1 | 80, 443, 2037 |
| 192.168.2.2 | 30, 70, 99 |
| 192.168.2.3 | 1020, 1070, 3020 |

Finally it should look like this:

| IP | System | Contact | DNS | Ports |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 192.168.2.1 | Gateway | xns | gati | 80, 443, 2037 |
| 192.168.2.2 | VM1 | etd | vm1etd | 30, 70, 99 |
| 192.168.2.3 | VM2 | rtf | vm2rtf | 1020, 1070, 3020 |

Answer (score 0):

What you need simply is `merge`:

```py
mergedDf = df1.merge(df2, on="IP") 
mergedDf
```